# KeyError: 'date' on yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, datetime

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

x = np.array(df['subscribersGained'].dropna().values, dtype=float)
y = np.array(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dropna()).index.values, dtype=float)
```

Error: KeyError: 'date'

In the .csv file, the date is in the format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: What data type is df?

Comment: Assuming it's a data frame is looks like that data frame has no index named date... I think the problem is a few lines before the code you posted.

Comment: If you want a numerical representation of datetime, try using dtype `int`, not float. That should give you nanoseconds since the Unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

By default, set_index() deletes the column that has been set as the index. Since it's been turned into the index trying to call it by name will raise the error. If you still want to use it as a data column as well you could try

```
df.set_index('date', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

The documentation for the function is also worth a read!
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: Thanks!

Now I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2018-12-21'

Comment: I can't quite figure out what data you're trying to extract for that y array but based on that error you're asking it to convert the timestamp data into a raw number which it can't do. I suspect you might not need so many function calls to get what you need.